# Drawing Graph from adjacancy list.

Tags: graph-theory

I'm struggling with drawing a graph from following exercise:
Set of vertices in undirected graph Gn is built from words of length n from alphabet {a,b,c,d}. Two words are adjacent when they have Hamming distance 1. Whats degree of Gn. How many vertices and edges does Gn have?

Now I know that degree is 3n, number of vertices: 4^n and edges: (3/2) * 4^n * n.
I'm unsure how to correctly picture edges for example in G2.

Comment: Just try: collect 16 points and label them with the edges of G2, then draw edges wherever you have a distance of 1.  To make things easier, you might start with four clusters of four points each, where each cluster corresponds to the words with a given letter in first position; for instance, the first cluster could be the words aa, ab, ac, ad, since you know those four will be connected to each other...

Comment: oh I see where I made a mistake. So initially I thought there will be 4 clusters each one with 4 points (a,b,c,d), but there are rather 16 points (aa,ab,ac,ad,bb,...). Am I right?

Comment: Enilonn: exactly; for convenience' sake you might want to break those 16 points into 4 clusters of 4 points each, but the labels on those 16 points should be all the two-letter words.

Answer (score 1):

If you have word aa, then what words is it connected to? all of the words of the form

(a,letter distinct from a) and
(letter distinct from a,a)